# Drupal 8 & Printer, Email & PDF - page not found

Tags: pdf-generation, drupal-8

I created a Drupal 8 website and i need to print PDF with datas. 
For this I installed pdf_api using composer and Printer, email and PDF versions for Drupal 8 and htmlpagedom (composer require "wa72/htmlpagedom").
The website URL is : http://drupal.test/

I can print page when i use classic printer at this URL : 
http://drupal.test/user/1/printable/print

But i have an error while clicking on pdf : page not found
http://drupal.test/user/1/printable/print

the PDF generation tool is : TCPDF

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by uninstalling Printer, email and PDF versions for Drupal 8 and reinstall it with composer ... 
I selected dompdf for generating the file...